# figure label inside standalone is not working. I am not able to refer the figure , its printing ??. my code is printed here

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, standalone

```
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{afterpage}% removing blank space before landscape
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

these are the packages i am using for the below figure

```
  \afterpage{
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}\label{fig:604}
            \centering
            \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{Comparison of Velocity ratio FEM,Experiment and Analytical}\end{minipage}},rotate=180,center}
                %\includestandalone[angle=90,width=\linewidth]{Velocity_ratio_comparison}
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{image001.png}
                %\caption{My caption}
            \end{adjustbox}     
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's a plain and simple mistake to place `\label` before `\caption` for `figure` and `table` floats. By placing `\label` before `\caption`, you've basically guaranteed that LaTeX cannot possibly resolve the `\ref`-based cross-reference correctly.

Comment: @marmot - This query is a duplicate of the plethora of postings which report placing `\label` before `\caption` and professing surprise at the fact that `\ref` cannot be resolved correctly.

Comment: @Mico That's true but there is also the fact be that floats are not working in the `standalone` class, and the title mentions `standalone`. That's why I was asking for an MWE.

Comment: @marmot - Of course, the use of a floating environment such as `figure` in a `standalone`-class document definitely raises a few more eyebrows...

Comment: Also figure inside landscape does not make any sense at all, the figure may float out of that landscape env and what ever it is you are attempting will be useless.